# Android 5 emulator not responding after few app launches

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Android studio v0.8.9 with latest Android SDK on Windows 7 64-bit. After running app four or five times in emulator with Android 5, emulator stops responding and I need to close and restart it.
Emulator crashes with this info:

```
Description: A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   emulator-x86.exe
...
```

I had no problems with other Android versions in emulator.